# How would I go about making a header in an Android Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

The header I'm looking for would look something like this:
[image]

Just need something to stay to the left, stay in the center, and stay to the right. Everything I have tried has had the center moved over a little towards the right so it looks off center. Any ideas or suggesstions?

EDIT:
This seems to be the closest I've been able to do with a simple amount of code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="First"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Second"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the code from your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll tell you how to do this. Set up a horizontal LinearLayout with layout_width of fill_parent and layout_height of wrap_content and weightSum of, in your case, 3. Fill it with three TextViews with layout_width set to fill_parent, layout_height set to wrap_content and layout_weight set to 1. Then the first TextView's gravity to "left", second one's to "center" and the third one's to "right". Done.

Comment: Amazing. Worked like a charm. I did not know about that whole weight sum property. Have to look that up. Just for quick reference. Will weight sum basically split the screen into whatever you give it? Let's say weight sum of 4. I will have 4 equal parts in my layout?

Comment: Hmm... My center text is displaying on 2 lines because its a bit too long. Any way for it to take advantage of the space left and right of it?

Comment: Well, kind of. The children need to match their parent's weighSum for it to work properly. For example, if you want three textviews share the space available, you set the weightSum to 3 and each child's layout_weight to 1. That would also work the same way if the LinearLayout's weightSum was 9 and all the TextViews had a layout_weight of 3. But if you set the weightSum to 4 and leave the layout_weight of the three TextViews to 1, it will not look as you would want it to look in your case.

Comment: For your overflow problem, just change the layout_width of all three TextViews to "wrap_content". That way the other two TextViews use only the space they need.

Comment: @Ebenezer: Play with different weight sums and weights for example weight sum 4 and weights of 1-2-1 gives a total of 4 but the centre textview will be twice the width of the ones on the left and right.

Comment: So I tried setting the first and last to .75 and my center to 1.5 So in total that gives me 3 but it messes up everything. Is there any idea you have to to have something stick to left and stick to right and then the center text starts and the center and expands?

Comment: @EbenezerAckon : look at my comment two rows up. It should work.

Comment: Yeah that fixed the overflow problem, it's just that the center isn't in the center of the screen it's in the center of the other two TextViews. Any other last minute suggestions?